# Develop conversational chatbot for chinese language in python

Tags: python, chatbot, wechat, chatterbot, xiaomi

I want to develop a conversational chatbot for chinese language in python like the user says "你好" which means "hello" in chinese and chatbot respond. i think it will be very difficult to build from scratch and write every expected response for chatbot. i want to find an opensource library to connect with my API which is able to respond to user and do the conservation with the user. i already know about a chatbot developed by Microsoft called "Xiaobing" which is especially developed for chinese people but i don't know if they provide an API for developers or not.There is also another github project called brobot(https://github.com/lizadaly/brobot/)
but i don't know if it provide chinese language support. Any suggestions or guidance from anyone here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ChatterBot](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) Python module. It is language independent. Means you can train it with any language.
sample snippet to train your bot.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot("bot")    # create an instance of ChatBot and name it.
chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

data = ["你好",
        "我很高兴认识你"]    # add data for training

chatbot.train(data)        # train the bot

while True:
    try:
        user_input = input("you - ")                 # ask something to bot
        bot_input = chatbot.get_response(user_input)   # get curresponding output from bot
        print("bot - ",bot_input)
    except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

**output**:

```
List Trainer: [####################] 100%
you - 你好
bot -  我很高兴认识你
```

You can train it with more and more conversations. Just add those conversation in a text file and train with it.
Refer ChatterBot docs for further information on training the data.

Comment: thanks. i understand it now but how to find training data for chinese language? because it will need a lot of work and will waste a lot of time if i write responses for bot

Comment: Yes. I agree. Collection of data is the the hardest part. But any chat bot you come across needs data. You can not find a single chat bot working without training with data.

Comment: thank you for your cooperation